# ECS remove all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have ECS cluster and i need to leave only registered by myself instance. The key is if I just delete it, ASG launches it again, is there any way to remove this one instance? I need only registered one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are trying to achieve is to only have ECS container instances that are registered manually (and not those that belong to that ASG) the easiest thing to do would be to either delete the ASG or (possibly better) set both the `min` and `max` number of instances for the ASG to `0`. This way the ASG won't spin up any new instance.

Comment: I see, thats what i expected, thanks I'm sure it will work